# Javascript assign the previously initialize object members a new value while looping

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem with passing by reference in Js Having a previously declared object

like that

```
parsed_data['nutrients_data'] = list[0].nutrients_data;
```

list is an array of objects and I am looping on list and do some calculations and assign the new values to data to be the average but didn't take the return value from parseFloat

```
console.log(parsed_data['nutrients_data'])
$.each(list, function(k, value) { 
  $.each(value.nutrients_data, function(key, value) {
          var avg = //some calculations
          var daily_value = //some calculations
          parsed_data['nutrients_data.'+key+'.value'] = parseFloat(avg.toPrecision(3));
          parsed_data['nutrients_data.'+key+'.daily_value'] = parseFloat(daily_value.toPrecision(3));
          console.log(parseFloat(avg.toPrecision(3)))
          console.log(parsed_data['nutrients_data.'+key+'.value'])
 })
 })
console.log(parsed_data['nutrients_data'])
```

the log shows that the object have the same values before and after the loop as Javascript pass it by reference so its ok.

But It shows that parseFloat returned float numbers but didn't affect  the object member values

log for one of the object members before the loop  :  2.2680000000000002

log for parseFloat returned value inside the loop  :  2.27

log for one of the object members after the loop  :  2.2680000000000002

Why the object member values didn't change to be float ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here:

```
parsed_data['nutrients_data.'+key+'.value'] = ...
```

...is writing to a property with the name `nutrients_data.somekey.value`. That is, the property name actually has the dots in it. The entire string you provide within the `[]` is used as a property name, it's not parsed into component parts the way code would be.

I suspect you want this:

```
parsed_data['nutrients_data'][key]['value'] = ...
```

...which you can write a bit more simply, like this:

```
parsed_data.nutrients_data[key].value = ...
```

Comment: You are right thanks a lot for your answer the log didn't show diff in object structure which was hidden for me !

Comment: @Mhmdgomma: Glad that helped. :-) If this answered your question, the way SO works, you "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. (But only if it did.) Best,